# Store every node of a tree in an array

Tags: generics, recursion, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, ada

I have to store every node of a generic tree which can be composed of any type. I have to do it in ADA but i just need the way to think.

I have to store every node in an Array of a generic element.
The way is that arrays don't have operations such as addition in Ada,
I mean i can't do :

`Array3:=Array1+Array2;`

the operator "+" is very useful for example to count recursively.

There is a way to do it recursively by storing every result on an array without use any operator ?

Or it is more convenient to do the algorithm iteratively ?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT The code in ADA that i've tried with concatenate operators of arrays

```
function Get_all_nodes (Current_Node : in Tree) return Something_Concatenation.Element_Array is 
array_of_results:Something_Concatenation.Element_Array(1..50);
begin
if (Tree_is_null(Current_Node)) then
    return array_of_results;
else
array_of_results(1):=Get_value_of_node(Current_Node);
array_of_results:= array_of_results & Get_all_nodes(Get_access_to_parent1(Current_Node));
array_of_results:= array_of_results & Get_all_nodes(Get_access_to_parent1(Current_Node));
end if;
return array_of_results;
end Get_all_nodes;
```

Regards

Comment: Do you have to write all the software yourself, or can you use the Ada standard library? Maybe you just need `Ada.Containers.Multiway_Trees` ([ARM A.18.10](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-A-18-10.html))

Comment: You can use the `&` function(s) defined by [`Ada.Containers.Vectors`](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-18-2.html) to concatenate elements as you traverse the tree.

Comment: I have to write all the software yourself, and not allowed to use Ada.Containers.vectors unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

In Ada, the [concatenation operator](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-4-5-3.html) is the `&` symbol.  Arrays can be concatenated together.  You can use that to do recursive calls if you like, but I wouldn't recommend it due to stack usage.  It's possible a compiler could optimize it but since you would be returning an unconstrained type, it may not.

You didn't specify the tree type or provide any code, so I cannot help you with how to get elements out of your tree type, but here is an example of array concatenation using generics:

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
procedure Hello is

    -- Generic, since you asked about it in a generic context
    generic
        type Element_Type is limited private;
    package Concatenation is
        type Element_Array is array(Positive range <>) of Element_Type;
    end Concatenation;

    -- Integer example
    package Integer_Concatenation is new Concatenation(Integer);
    use type Integer_Concatenation.Element_Array;

    a1 : Integer_Concatenation.Element_Array(1..4) := (others => 1);
    a2 : Integer_Concatenation.Element_Array(1..5) := (others => 2);
    a3 : Integer_Concatenation.Element_Array := a1 & a2;
    a4 : Integer_Concatenation.Element_Array := 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5;

    -- Custom record type
    type Something is null record;
    package Something_Concatenation is new Concatenation(Something);
    use type Something_Concatenation.Element_Array;

    a5 : Something_Concatenation.Element_Array(1..4) := (others => <>);
    a6 : Something_Concatenation.Element_Array(1..5) := (others => <>);
    a7 : Something_Concatenation.Element_Array := a5 & a6;

    s1,s2,s3,s4,s5 : Something;
    a8 : Something_Concatenation.Element_Array := s1 & s2 & s3 & s4 & s5;
begin
    -- Show the integer array results
    Put_Line("Hello, world!");
    for E of a3 loop
        Put(Integer'Image(E));
    end loop;
    New_Line;
    for E of a4 loop
        Put(Integer'Image(E));
    end loop;
    New_Line;
end Hello;
```

EDIT:  You edited your question with an attempt at recursion.  Here is an alternate example of the recursion so you can see some options you have for syntax and setup.  I had to stub in a bunch of things since you didn't provide much.  Also, earlier I provided the array type via a generic because your original question asked about in the context of generics.  In real life, I wouldn't create a Generic just for the array type (that can be done anywhere).  Instead, you would have a generic for your tree and all the stuff mentioned in this answer would be done in the context of that generic.  Since you didn't provide any skeleton generic code, I didn't want to make a whole example up.  I just wanted to show you that concatenation would work with types created via generics.

```ada
    function Get_all_nodes (Current_Node : in Tree) return 
        Something_Concatenation.Element_Array 
    is 
        use Something_Concatenation;
        use type Element_Array;
        Next_Node : Tree;
    begin
        if (Tree_is_null(Current_Node)) then
            return (1..0 => <>);  -- returns a null array
        else
            -- for the next call, get the node after this one
            -- or replace this with a call for the previous one
            -- or whatever your mechanism for getting a new
            -- node is.  You can also call Get_Next_Node
            -- in the return statement.  I Pulled it out
            -- here so you would see the step
            Next_Node := Get_Next_Node(Current_Node);

            -- here you need to figure out the order of nodes
            -- and how you want to traverse them.  This is
            -- just a basic (probably logically wrong) example
            -- to show you the syntax you were trying to emulate.
            -- you might also have to alter the order of these
            -- elements to get the array element order you want
            return Element_Array'(1 => Get_Value_of_Node(Current_Node))
                & Get_All_Nodes(Next_Node);

            -- Alternate with no "Next_Node" variable:
            -- return Element_Array'(1 => Get_Value_of_Node(Current_Node))
            --    & Get_All_Nodes(Get_Next_Node(Current_Node));
        end if;
    end Get_all_nodes;
```

Comment: I try it and its seems the good solution, now i just have to find a way to not have a length problem.

Comment: Careful use of [stack variables](https://www.adacore.com/uploads_gems/07_safe_secure_ada_2005_safe_memory_management.pdf) can minimize the length problem.

Comment: I updated the solution to help give some ideas for the recursion part.  Again though, I recommend doing iteration instead if possible.  trashgod's link is also very good to read over.

Answer (score 0):

So i've tried the recursive and iterative version.
In iterative version, i got something like this, i've used stacks which is allowed in my cases

```
function get_all_nodes(Current_Node:in Tree) return Stack is
--declarations
My_Stack: Stack;
copy:Tree;
finished: Boolean:=False;
begin
--Initialisation

copy:=Current_Node;
My_Stack:=Initialisation;
--beginning by pushing the first node on the stack

push_on_stack(stack,copy.all.elt);

while(copy/=null or finished =False) loop
--check that we can put the first parent on stack
    if(copy.all.parent1/=null and not Found_in_Stack(My_Stack,copy.all.parent1.all.elt)) then
        copy:=copy.all.parent1;
        push_on_stack(stack,copy.all.elt);
    end if;
--check that we can put the second parent on stack
    if(copy.all.parent2/=null and not Found_in_Stack(My_Stack,copy.all.parent2.all.elt)) then
        copy:=copy.all.parent2;
        push_on_stack(stack,copy.all.elt);
    end if;
--check we are on case where both parents are already on stack or both null
    if(copy.all.parent1=null and copy.all.parent2=null) or 
    (Found_in_Stack(My_Stack,copy.all.parent1.all.elt) and (Found_in_Stack(My_Stack,copy.all.parent2.all.elt))) then
    --check we are on case where we are back to first node and then it's finished 
        if(copy.all.elt=Current_Node.all.elt) then
            finished:=True;
        else
        --go back to previous node thanks to stack
            copy:= First_Element_after_top_of_stack(My_Stack);
        end if;
    end if;
end loop;
return My_Stack;
end get_all_nodes;
```

And i got some errors somewhere at this point

```
copy.all.parent2/=null and not Found_in_Stack(My_Stack,copy.all.parent2.all.elt)
```

Where it's seems to execute the second condition after the first one and i get error because copy.all.parent2.all.elt = null instead the generic element which is on the stack and on the tree .

I tried the recursive version by this code:

```
function get_all_nodes (Current_Node : in Tree) return Integer_Concatenation.Element_Array is
use Integer_Concatenation;
use type Element_Array;
begin
if(Tree_is_null(Current_Node)) then
return (1..0 => <>);
else
return Element_Array'(1 => Get_node_value(Current_Node)) & get_all_nodes(Current_Node.all.parent1) & get_all_nodes(Current_Node.all.parent2);
end if;
end get_all_nodes;
```

I've got one  CONSTRAINT_ERROR of length check failed.

For now i will check how to minimize length problem by reading trashgod link , otherwise i will check if i can use the Ada containers.

Thanks again for your help everyone.
Regards.